# Linking Moodle with Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, moodle

I have recently installed moodle-2.8.3 and alfresco-community-5.0.c on my local.

I did the tutorial from [packtpub.com](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/integrating-moodle-20-alfresco-manage-content-business)

My moodle and alfresco works well independently, but when I try to add a file from an alfresco repository I cannot connect to this one.

I have added the alfresco link

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/alfresco/api
```

in the moodle alfresco plugin

Here is a screenshot showing where I try to connect to Alfresco : [image]

When I type the admin login and password from Alfresco, nothing happens, the page remains the same.

Someone could explain my why ? : /

Edit : When I hit http://127.0.0.1:8080/alfresco/api on my browser I have the following :

```
{"list":{"pagination":{"count":1,"hasMoreItems":false,"totalItems":1,"skipCount":0,"maxItems":100},"entries":[{"entry":{"id":"-default-","quotas":[],"isEnabled":true}}]}}
```

Comment: Can you link to the tutorial? We might be able to see something wrong from there

Comment: Sorry I didn't link it, I had a link restriction when I made my post. Here it is : https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/integrating-moodle-20-alfresco-manage-content-business

Comment: Any errors in the logs of Alfresco or Moodle?

Comment: That tutorial looks to me like it's written for an older version of Alfresco than the one you're running. Have you checked for an updated tutorial or install guide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using a tutorial written for Alfresco 4.0 or 4.1 on a 5.x install

On Alfresco 4.x, the URL you mention `http://127.0.0.1:8080/alfresco/api` points to the [Alfresco Web Services Endpoint](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_Content_Management_Web_Services).

On Alfresco 5, that endpoint URL has changed, to make way for the new RESTful public API. The new URL for the old webservices API is at `http://localhost:8080/alfresco/soapapi`

If you update your configuration to point to `http://localhost:8080/alfresco/soapapi` instead, then it ought to work, as you'll then be pointing Moodle at the API it expects (from your tutorial Moodle wants the old WebServices WS* API, not the newer RESTful or CMIS ones)

Comment: Sorry for the time between response. I didn't checked this, it worked :)